# Difficulty investigating faulty hardware

Tags: hard-drive, memory, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I've had some issues with my PC which I built some time ago. This is my first time building a PC, so a bit of a noob here.

There are two main problems with it and I cannot diagnose what is causing it or if a hardware is faulty.

1. When I turn off the computer, it automatically restarts every time, but just when it turns off I switch down the power and wait a couple of seconds, then I can switch the power on again without it restarting
2. Sometimes, my computer freezes, the mouse cursor works but nothing is clickable or working, then after half a minute it unfreezes on its own. This happens randomly, no matter how hard I push the machine. Sometimes, I'm just browsing, sometimes I am playing a game. In some rare cases it gives me the blue screen of death or restarts completely. (this one started to become worse these days)

To get to the first issue, I double-checked if all the power and power switch cables are connected well to the motherboard and they are. I am guessing a hardware wakes up the PC, but I am kind of in the dark.

For the second issue, I am thinking a RAM of video card issue, but I cannot replace and check as I have no spares. I'm not sure if the power unit is big enough and that might cause the issue. Or possibly an overheating problem. These are just guesses.

So my question is if you guys know some diagnostic software or any other ways I can find out what is wrong of what is faulty in my setup. Or maybe you had similar issues and want to share what the issue was and how you fixed it.

My specs:
* Gigabyte 970A-DS3P AMD 970 Motherboard (Socket AM3+, DDR3, S-ATA 600, ATX, PCI Express 2.0 x16, USB 3.0)
* AMD FX8350 Black Edition 8 Core Processor (4.0/4.2GHz, 8MB Level 3 Cache, 8MB Level 2 Cache, Socket AM3+, 125W) 
* 16GB RAM 3 x Kingston (8 + 4 + 4)
* MSI R9 270X 2048 MB
* Corsair CXM 500W

inside a:
* Xigmatek Recon USB 3.0 Midi-Tower

Disk drives:
* Samsung 840 EVO 500GB 2.5-inch Basic SATA - with the OS
* WD 1TB 3.5 inch Internal Hard Drive (2x)

Op. System:
Windows 10 Pro v. 1803

EDIT:
I've run a surface scan. Apparently no errors on either of the discs. However, I've noticed quite high temperatures. Maybe that's the issue? 85C on CPU, 70C on GPU, and 60-70 on discs

EDIT:
I've downloaded gsmartcontrol and ran an extended scan on all hard discs, and all of them returned no errors. I've bought a bigger psu 850W and a case with better airflow and 3 fans to try better cooling. If all else fails, I'll try and install windows on one of the HDDs and test each disc separately. I'll also try new SATA cables. However, I've also got new symptoms. Today I got the blue screen of death while playing a game, and my bluetooth keyboard and mouse somrtimes lag to respond as well.

EDIT:

Ok. I've replaced the case and psu. The auto-restart issue went away with this, and the system seemed all right for a while, but now I got the blue screen of death for a couple of times with Windows saying it couldn't start, trying to apply repairs and then failing. According to the logs in the srtTrail.log file there is an error:

---

Boot critical file f:\boot\resources\custom\bootres.dll is corrupt.

Repair action: File repair
Result: Failed. Error code =  0x2
Time taken = 2156 ms

---

Problem is I do not have a F drive. Can it be the system reserved partitioned off from drive c?

Comment: First thing I would check is the hard drives. Try chkdsk in command prompt. Run the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: Intermittent *recoverable* hangs without indication sounds like a hard drive or or power supply issue to me. If it was the graphics card browning out then the OS would 've telling you that something happened to the graphics card and the driver was reset and system RAM failures would be much more consistant. Could be a voltage regulator in the PSU or hard drive it at its limit. 500W sounds a bit conservative for an AMD processor and graphics card.

Comment: I've run chkdsk in administrator mode and all 3 of my hard drives are fine.

Comment: Have you done a full surface scan? By default chkdsk only checks filesystem integrity and not the actual disk surface. The areas of disk where the filesystem metadata are stored could well be fine but chkdsk would not (by default) detect areas of disk that have bad sectors or a disk that occasionally browns out due to a power supply problem. As a diagnostic tool chkdsk is the equivalent of opening the bonnet of your car to check whether or not your exhaust has fallen off.

Comment: I've run a surface scan. Apparently no errors on either of the discs. However, I've noticed quite high temperatures. Maybe that's the issue? 85C on CPU, 70C on GPU, and 60-70 on discs

Comment: Run `gsmartcontrol` (download and install it from sourceforge - google it) and make it run a short self-test on each of your HDD/SSDs. `chkdsk` will not find problems other than bad sectors, but other sorts of problems are possible.

Comment: Check the event viewer for VPU recovery events. If, when you turn off your computer, you pull power from it (like switching off a plug strip), then the 1st issue may be "double POST at boot." This is usually fixed by firmware from motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: The hangs you describe are most likely caused by the storage not responding. It could be as simple as a faulty SATA cable.

Comment: I've downloaded gsmartcontrol and ran an extended scan on all hard discs, and all of them returned no errors. I've bought a bigger psu 850W and a case with better airflow and 3 fans to try better cooling. If all else fails, I'll try and install windows on one of the HDDs and test each disc separately. I'll also try new SATA cables. However, I've also got new symptoms. Today I got the blue screen of death while playing a game, and my bluetooth keyboard and mouse somrtimes lag to respond as well.

Comment: The shutdown, then restart is easy... disable Windows Fast Boot or Fast Startup, sometimes called Hybrid Shutdown, and that problem will likely go away.

Comment: Ok. I've replaced the case and psu. The auto-restart issue went away with this, and the system seemed all right for a while, but now I got the blue screen of death for a couple of times with Windows saying it couldn't start, trying to apply repairs and then failing. According to the logs in the srtTrail.log file there is an error:
---------------------------
Boot critical file f:\boot\resources\custom\bootres.dll is corrupt.

Repair action: File repair
Result: Failed. Error code =  0x2
Time taken = 2156 ms
Problem is I do not have a F drive. Can it be the system reserved drive from c?